# How to fill an array that is full of values type Hello with strings?

Tags: java, typeerror

I am at the very end of a homework assignment and can not for the life of my figure out how to do this. Basically I have an array that is full of null values that are all type Hello. I need to fill this array with a bunch of strings I have created. This is the error I am getting:

```
incompatible types
required: Hello
found: String
```

Is it possible for me to change my strings to type Hello? Or is there something else I am completely missing here?

Here is how my array is initalized:
I'll change the i to 3 to make it simpler

```
Hello[] array = new Hello[3];
```

I don't do anything fancy to fill the array:

```
test = "1 two three";
Hello[0] = test;
```

Comment: show us some code plz ??

Comment: I don't really know what code would help with the answer. My problem is pretty much completely explained above.

Comment: So...you have a `Hello` array defined by the bound of `i`.  That doesn't tell us much except that the array is null.  Do you need to know how to instantiate every object in the array?

Comment: show us the code where you are filling that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is a `Hello` object constructed? My guess is that it takes a `String` argument. So you would do something like:

```
Hello hello = new Hello(myString);
myHelloArray[index] = hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement Hello[] array = new Hello[3]; state that you are trying to create array of Hello Object. so each element in the array can only point to object of Hello class and here you are trying to assign object of String class into Hello. 
You have to create Hello object first and then assign to array element.

Answer (score 0):

As you have described above , the array takes Hello type 
below is the class Hello having constructor which takes String type elements
and a MainHello class which will have main method and will consume Hello type array
for your Convenience i have overrided toString() ;) hope it will help you, thanks

```
public class Hello {

    String hello;

    Hello(String hello){        
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return hello;
    }

}

public class MainHello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Hello[] helloArray = new Hello[4] ;
         helloArray[0] = new Hello("soumyaansh");
         helloArray[1] = new Hello("user1294377");
         helloArray[2] = new Hello("india");
         helloArray[3] = new Hello("Bangalore");

        for (Hello hello : helloArray) {
            System.out.println(hello.toString());
        }

    }
}
```